# Objective-C iOS: Begin populating UITableView immediately from JSON Stream

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsjsonserialization

I have a `UITableView` with cells to display images and text from a largish (5000 items) JSON file. I want to stream the JSON in and start updating the `UITableView` immediately, but can't seem to work out the plumbing for this.

```
- (NSArray *)parseJSONIntoImageObjectsFromData:(NSData *)rawJSONData {
  NSError *error;
  NSMutableArray *arrayOfImageObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:self.urlString];
  NSData *objects = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
  NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:objects];
  [stream open];

  NSMutableArray *arrayFromStream = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:stream options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

  for (NSDictionary *JSonDictionary in arrayFromStream) {
    NSLog(@"Count is %lu", (unsigned long)arrayOfImageObjects.count);
    NSInteger imgID = (NSInteger)JSonDictionary[@"id"];
    ImageObject *newImageObject = [[ImageObject alloc] initWithID:imgID andTitle:JSonDictionary[@"title"] andThumbnailURL:JSonDictionary[@"thumbnailUrl"]];
    [arrayOfImageObjects addObject:newImageObject];
  }
  return arrayOfImageObjects;
}
```

This definitely gets them as a stream, as the `NSLog` reveals in the debug window. But since it waits for the return it has to complete. I'm a little puzzled at going about this and can't find a good code sample. Do I perhaps return a stream?

**EDIT:** I am not terribly concerned about the brief delay I am encountering and I am sure the delay is more on the retrieval than in the parsing, I just want to learn to retrieve the data as a stream and update the `UITableView` incrementally as a way to do this better. I enjoy working on data retrieval and manipulation and am trying to improve my skills by knowing more.

Also, the images are retrieved asynchronously at display time using an `NSOperationQueue` and don't really matter for this task.

Comment: This can be a worthwhile optimization, but have you measured how long it takes to parse 5000 JSON objects? If the JSON objects themselves aren't too large that's likely to take negligibly long.

Comment: @MaxGabriel It's about 5 seconds with download and parse, not bad at all, but seems like a really useful thing to learn.

Comment: you might also consider "paging" your data. So only retrieve 100 objects at a time (if you have that ability with your API), and then use something like tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to determine when to load the next set of objects.

Comment: @NateBirkholz "It's about 5 seconds with download and parse". This heavily depends on the network bandwidth. As a rule of thumb, with `NSJSONSerialization` we can create an object representation from a given 1 Mbyte UTF-8 JSON in about 25ms to 40ms on a recent hardware, like iPhone 5s. There are even faster parsers.

Answer (score 2):

If you benchmark this, I think you'll find that the parsing time of the JSON is inconsequential. The slow parts are going to be the download of the original JSON (and possibly the creation of the `ImageObject` objects). You should benchmark this in Instruments (use the "time profiler" tool) and use the "record waiting threads" option. See WWDC video [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) for a demonstration on how to use Instruments to diagnose these sorts of issues.

I would first retire the `dataWithContentsOfURL`, as that runs synchronously. I would advise using an asynchronous technique such as `NSURLSession` method `dataWithURL` (or if you need support for pre-iOS 7, `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest`).

Usually in these cases, the JSON is small enough, that the biggest delay stems from the network latency in making the initial request. I mention that so that you don't bother embarking on some major refactoring of the code for paging/streaming approaches without confirming that this will solve the problem.

Also, you haven't shared this `ImageObject` logic, but if that is synchronously loading images, that's a likely candidate for refactoring for asynchronous retrieval, too. Without knowing more about that class, it's hard to advise you further on that point.

Comment: Thanks. I was originally using the `NSURLSession` method `dataWithURL` to get the data and then parse it, but I found some past references to using `dataWithContentsOfURL` and wanted to see if I could get the stream working. I'll poke around more in `NSURLSession` and see what I can find. The images are retrieved asynchronously on demand via `NSOperationsQueue` and a local cache, btw. This is a personal project for the purposes of improving my familiarity with the `NSURLSession` and `NSJSONSerialization` frameworks. Refactoring is what it's there for.

Comment: I can imagine what you were trying to do with the stream (it's a technique you can use with really large XML, to stream contents directly to persistent storage, as you parse it, with minimal memory footprint), but it won't accomplish anything with JSON. You need a delegate-based parser, like `libxml` or `NSXMLParser` for that to have a chance at success.

Answer (score 1):

Define `NSMutableArray *arrayOfImageObjects`as a property or variable outside this method and then in your for loop, call [self.tableView reloadData] after maybe every 100 objects.

That's assuming that your numberOfRowsInSection is keying off of arrayOfImageObjects as well and cellForRowAtIndexPath is using it to populate the table data.

But also consider 'paging' your data, so as to only load 50 objects or so, at once (assuming your API supports this like 'http://example.com/imagedata?page=1'). Then if the user flicks or scrolls the tableview you can do another api call, increasing the page number and adding that new set of data to your current set and calling reloadData.

**EDIT**: also I'm assuming your "parseJSONIntoImageObjectsFromData" is running asynchronously. If not then use something like AFNetworking (or sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: in NSURLConnection)  and in the completion block you can start adding to your array.

Comment: Thanks. The API I am using doesn't do that seemingly, or I'd have used that. I'll give this a try tomorrow, it sounds interesting. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: And yes, the parse function is called inside an asynchronous queue.